# Optional regular expression match

Tags: regex

I have an string like `1566-02`, where `-02` is optional. If I use a regular expression like this

```
1566\s*-\s*\d{2}
```

it will always expect 2 numeric number with hyphen after `1566`.

How I can make the `-02` part optional, so that the `IsMatch` should be true for 1566 also?

For example -
The value of IsMatch should be true if we pass the string as 1566 or 1566-02 or 1566-45
IsMatch value should be false for 1566-AC or 1566-

Comment: Please specify what language / platform you're using. Given that you mentioned `IsMatch` is this .NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply wrap it in a [group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and make it optional with the zero-or-one [quantifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (`?`):

```
1566(\s*-\s*\d{2})?
```

To prohibit any other characters before or after the matched string, use start (`^`) and end (`$`) [anchors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
^1566(\s*-\s*\d{2})?$
```

Comment: IsMatch value should be - true for 1566, 1566-23 but it should be false for 1566-AB. In this case everything becomes true

Comment: Thank you so much p.s.w.g - it meets my requirement